# Putting logout action in a <a> tag

Tags: html

I want to make a logout link in my User dropdown menu.. But i cant seem to set the "action" attribute to a link tag (`<a>`) i dont want to put it in a form, i would like to make it when they click logout it just locks out.

This is my working logout `<Button>` which i do not want to use.

```
<form action="./includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

I would like to include the logout link in my Drop down:

```
<div class='dropdown' style='float:right;'>
   <li class='login current2'><a href='#'>Welcome</a>
      <div class='dropdown-content'>
         <ul>
            <li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='#'>My Account</a></la>
            <li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='#'>My Orders</a></la>
            <li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='#'>My Wishlist</a></la>
            <li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='#'>My Cart</a></la>
            <li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='#'>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Is there a way i can make the line:

```
<li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='#'>Logout</a></li>
```

Work the same as the button but without the `<form>` tag and the `<button>` tag?

Comment: if you don't want JS code you may need just `GET` instedof `POST` and the link will be `./includes/logout.inc.php?logout-submit`

Comment: @MamdouhFreelance i wouldnt mind JS if it would make it easier.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a form? You can style the button to look like a link.

Comment: @JonP when i use a form it messes up the alignment of my text, i will edit with a picture of the dropdown with the form tag.

Comment: @CoreyRinda sounds like just a styling issue, if you can post a working sample of your code we can better understand it.

Comment: If you use the proper CSS to normalize any user-agent styles on form elements, you won't have any problems with text alignment. Also, this may not make sense yet but the proper way to log a user out is to use a POST request from a form, simply because a GET request can cause unexpected problems and security vulnerabilities with CSRF. --> https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59411/how-to-protect-against-login-csrf/59529#59529

Comment: @jaredgorski Your comment is correct and I'd upvote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by ensuring your PHP script uses $_GET instead of $_POST and just use your link like:

```
<li style='font-size:10px;'><a href='./includes/logout.inc.php?logout-submit=logout'>Logout</a></li>
```

In `logout.inc.php` you would do something similar to:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout-submit']) && $_GET['logout-submit'] == 'logout'){
  // run logout code
}
```

Comment: But then it's a GET request and not a POST request.

Comment: I literally said that in my answer.

Comment: Logouts should be POST requests because they change state and need CSRF protection. The OP appeared to recognize that using POST was a good idea, but was having trouble implementing it.

Comment: If you have concerns you can raise your own question instead of spamming comments. This answers the OPs question hence him marking it correct. Instead of assuming what the OP wanted try reading what he tells you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution just handle it as `GET` request from server side.

```
<a href="./includes/logout.inc.php?logout-submit">Logout</a>
```

If you would like do that in JavaScript, use `document.createElement()` & `.appendChild()`.

Check [HTML DOM Form Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_form.asp)

```js
function logout() {
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.action = "./includes/logout.inc.php";
  form.method = "post";
  var sbmt = document.createElement("input");
  sbmt.name = "logout-submit";
  form.appendChild(sbmt);
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="logout()">Logout</a>
```